# Android (Service class) - Only first time works getApplicationContext()

Tags: android, android-webview

I use webview and Javascript Interface to communicate with a web app.

For example, I have code for notification from my other project (working version).

In OnCreate i define (static):

```
PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```

PACKAGE_NAME works in notification method but not getApplicationContext().getPackageName() .I replaced i fixed .

1) **How to create variable for = getApplicationContext().getResources()**

```
  if (CURRENT__ == 1) {
            contentNotify =new RemoteViews( PACKAGE_NAME , R.layout.big2);
            contentNotifySmall = new RemoteViews( PACKAGE_NAME , R.layout.small1 );
        }
        else {
            contentNotify =new RemoteViews(PACKAGE_NAME, R.layout.big1);
            contentNotifySmall = new RemoteViews(PACKAGE_NAME, R.layout.small2 );
        }


 icon  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
// NOT EXECUTE CODE FROM HERE (only first time)
 icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getApplicationContext().getResources()  , R.drawable.ic_launcher);

 mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
 mBuilder.setShowWhen(false);

 etc.
```

First time I start services in mainActivity and in services class on onStartCommand I call Notification method.

After that, I call notification method from Javascript (JS interface).

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: I want to switch this getApplicationContext().getResources() intro variable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Context.getApplicationContext().getResources()` returns a [Resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) object, so you can store it in that:

```
Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
```